# Background image of UITabbar ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbar

I want to set a custom image as background image of a UITabbar.

I know that there should be different sizes of them available in the app to support retina and non-retina, 640x98 and 320x49 respectively and also add the @2x prefix to the retina image name.

The image I want to use is not symmetric, i.e, the colors change a bit as you look at the image from left to right.

The problem I have is that the image fit the fine inside the tabbar on Iphone 4s, 5 and 5s but it doesn't fit on Iphone 6, 6 plus, 6s, 6s plus etc.

I guess it has to do with that there are wider screens on the Iphone 6 series. When I increase the width of the image it does fit inside the Iphone 6 series but not on 4s, 5 and 5s (only 2/3 of the image can be seen).

**Senario**

When I try to run on 4s, 5, and 5s with a image of size 320x49 it fits fine. When I run with 640x98 the image is too wide.

When I try to run 320x49 on the 6 series the image is not wide enough to fill the whole tabbar, and hence it's gets tiled (looks weird).
When I run on the 6 series with 640x98 it's fits well.

However I can't seem to combine those two settings, or what am I missing?

Thanks, Muff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the images with different sizes into the image assets file.
When u create a new set in it, it'll show options for different sizes (1x,2x,3x). You can also right click and select the device you are targeting. There are Universal, iPhone, iPad, Apple TV, Apple watch and Mac. and when u call the image it'll set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple in swift just give the tab bar an outlet and do this:

```
tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "image")
```

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to set it with  `var bg_image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"tab_bar_bg.png")!
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = bg_image`  

in app delegate. The problem is that the image doesn't seem scale to fit the screen properly on different iOS devices.


And also, I'm using a tabbar controller and I can't find a way to make an outlet of it, but it shouldn't matter?